# Azure Table Storage Bit Data Type

Tags: c#, azure, bit-manipulation, azure-storage

I am architecting a table for my `Azure Table Storage` based app, and I need it to have 100 "columns" with `bit` or `boolean` datatypes.

I can obviously store `int` flags as my column datatype, but since there are 100 per table entry, I would like to make the entries (aka, "rows") as small as possible. If I use `int` flags, my entry size will be `100 bytes`, but if I'm able to use a **`bit`** datatype, then it is obviously 8 times smaller.

`Booleans` seem like they should work in theory, but I just read ([here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8d779c1f-561e-4001-a917-f094c4efa65d/doubt-in-size-of-boolean)) that Booleans take a full byte in memory.

Is there a way to have a datatype that is truly **`1 bit`** in size and able to be stored in `Azure Table Storage`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The Windows Azure Storage REST API documentation provides the definitive specification of what can be done with Azure Tables. The data model and supported datatypes are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179338.aspx).

Since individual columns aren't indexed and result in a table scan when queried, could you not use some other storage mechanism for the data. For example, you could store the data in a byte[] property in a Table entity. Indeed, if the only data you are storing in the entity are these bits then you could even use blobs instead.